# In Emacs org-mode, how do I get org-capture to open in a full-sized window?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, how do I get org-capture to open in a full-sized window, rather than first splitting the window ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'delete-other-windows)` or `(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'make-frame)` to your `.emacs`. (To test, you can eval these with `M-:`). The first should delete the other windows, the second opens the window in a new frame. However these work *after* you select the capture template.

Comment: I modified your code to `(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook 'sticky-window-delete-other-windows)` and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work for me in emacs 24. The only solution I was able to find involves using [emacs-noflet](https://github.com/nicferrier/emacs-noflet) and (thanks [Alex Vorobiev](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2013-10/msg00150.html)) in your emacs file:

```
 (defun make-capture-frame ()
     "Create a new frame and run org-capture."
     (interactive)
     (make-frame '((name . "capture")))
     (select-frame-by-name "capture")
     (delete-other-windows)
     (noflet ((switch-to-buffer-other-window (buf) (switch-to-buffer buf)))
       (org-capture)))
```

and bind `make-capture-frame` to a shortcut.

Comment: It works for me and I'm on Emacs 24.3.1. I am referring to a full window, rather than a split window. (Not a `maximize-frame` frame.) It doesn't work for you?

Comment: It works for me and I'm on Emacs 24.3.1. I am referring to a full Emacs window, rather than splitting the frame into two windows. (I am not referring to a full-screen `maximize-frame` frame.) It doesn't work for you?

Comment: Interesting. It was opening in a split window, with the scratch buffer above `org-capture`. That's the only way I could get it to work in 24.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers seemed to work for me on doom emacs 28.2 (June 2023), so author of org-gtd.el and sqlup.el kindly [solved it on reddit yesterday](https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/14bx0v4/open_orgcapture_frame_maximized_to_the_window/joiqmlg/?context=8&depth=9). Copied below is his snippet:

*If you are on doom emacs make sure to add it to the `(after! org ...) block`.

```
(defun stag-misanthropic-capture (&rest r)
  (delete-other-windows))

(advice-add  #'org-capture-place-template :after 'stag-misanthropic-capture)
```

and how it can be invoked from command line (for "todo template"):

```
emacsclient -e '(org-capture nil "t")' --create-frame
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to ensure that org-capture opened in a new frame, and that the frame was closed when finished.  The following worked well for this:

```
    ; close capture frames when finished capturing
    (add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook (lambda () (delete-frame)))

    ; make org-capture open up as sole window in a new frame
    (defadvice org-capture (around my-org-capture activate)
       (progn
          (select-frame (make-frame))
          (delete-other-windows)
          (noflet
             ((switch-to-buffer-other-window (buf) (switch-to-buffer buf)))
             ad-do-it)))
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in spacemacs "switch-to-buffer-other-window" gives me "invalid function".